# ECONOMICS: These expected payoffs are gross of the ticket price. What does GROSS means here?

Tags: meaning

*These expected payoffs are gross of the ticket price.*

I am unsure about the meaning of the word *gross* here.

Does it mean the expected payoffs are including the ticket price or are they excluding the ticket price?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that questions which can be answered by common references such as dictionaries are not accepted here; *[gross](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gross_1): a gross amount of money is the total amount before taxes or costs have been taken out* (MMD). I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: The sentence has no mention of profits, only payoffs.  Show us what you found for "gross" in a dictionary.

Comment: The problem is that I am not a native English speaker, so the definition (which was the first think I searched) does not answer my question. 

The definition: Gross: (of income, profit, or interest) without deduction of tax or other contributions; total

Comment: And why does that definition not answer your question?

Comment: Please note: usually, one speaks of some price being net of some amount or fee or tax. Personally, I have never heard "gross of a price". In that sense, the question does seem reasonable re usage. And apparently this is used in a calculus formula: http://toomas.hinnosaar.net/overbooking.pdf which I don't understand, so I cannot help.

Comment: Why is this a question for EL&U and not Economics?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that having a ticket gives you the same expected payoff (i.e. happiness) as V dollars and the ticket costs p dollars. Then your expected payoff from having the ticket (gross of the ticket price) is V and your expected payoff from buying the ticket (net of the ticket price) is V-p.